# Find the steady-state of the heat equation $u_t = u_{xx} + f(x), −1 < x < 1, t > 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the steady-state of the heat equation $u_t = u_{xx} + f(x), −1 < x < 1, t > 0$

$u(−1, t) = u(1, t) = 0$, $f(x) = -2 $ if $ − 1 < x < 0$ and
$0 $ if $ 0 ≤ x < 1$
(NOTE: $u(−1) = u(1) = 0)$

I know that for steady state the temperature will no longer vary with time, so we can write it as $0 = d^2T/dx^2 + f(x)$.
With our conditions it will be $0 = d^2T/dx^2, 0 = d^2T/dx^2 - 2$ and we do normal integration of these equations and obtain $0 = Ax + B, 0 = -x^2 + Cx + D$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here to find the steady state.

Comment: Next step: Enforce the boundary conditions in each region. This will give you two constraints on $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$. Then: Make the function $T$ and its first derivative continuous at $x=0$. This will give you two more constraints. Also: That should be $+x^2$, not $-x^2$.

Comment: @JohnBarber thanks! Since we integrate -2, shouldn't it be $-x^2$?

Comment: No, because the $2$ moves over to the other side of the equals sign and therefore loses the minus: $d^2 T/dx^2 = 2$.